# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 4276: invalid start byte

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8

I try to read and print the following file: txt.tsv (https://www.sec.gov/files/dera/data/financial-statement-and-notes-data-sets/2017q3_notes.zip)

According to the SEC the data set is provided in a single encoding, as follows:

> Tab Delimited Value (.txt): utf-8, tab-delimited, \n- terminated lines, with the first line containing the field names in lowercase.

My current code:

```
import csv

with open('txt.tsv') as tsvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(tsvfile, dialect='excel-tab')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

All attempts ended with the following error message:

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 4276: invalid start byte

I am a bit lost. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can we see the file you are using?

Comment: Also, is this Python 2 or 3? The answer is *very* important, since the `csv` module is broken for non-ASCII on Python 2.

Comment: I am using Python 3.6.0

Comment: Hmm... On rereading the error, I'm pretty sure the problem is your input file. The error indicates it is trying to read it as `utf-8`, so your input likely doesn't follow the format described. That said, the file you linked seems to follow it just fine (it's pure ASCII AFAICT; it uses some unusual ASCII control characters, but they're all in the ASCII range), so I'm not sure where you'd see a `\xa0` byte. Is it possible you modified the file by accident before using it?

Comment: see below the answer of Kopytok. if I change the encoding to 'windows-1252' it works perfect.

Comment: A side-note: You should be passing `newline=''` to `open` when working with CSV-like stuff. And the `excel_tab` dialect is wrong here; it assumes line endings are `\r\n`, when the file is `\n` endings. Defining your own dialect based off `excel_tab` would be an easy solution, just subclass it and set the class level variable `lineterminator = '\n'`

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Encoding in the file is 'windows-1252'. Use:

```
open('txt.tsv', encoding='windows-1252')
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! That works! May I ask you why it works with 'windows-1252' although the SEC states it is 'utf-8'?

Comment: Are you sure it's cp1252? The file I downloaded appeared to be ASCII. If it's not UTF-8, and not ASCII, it could be literally any single-byte-per-character ASCII superset and you'd only be able to guess at the encoding heuristically (it would successfully decode under any of them, but the results might be garbage).

Comment: @Vital Better ask SEC

Comment: @ShadowRanger encoding detector detected cp-1252 and the result seems to be legit

Comment: This has the potential of producing invalid results. CP-1252 will happily decode *anything* (audio data, core dumps, zip archives) and pretend it's all valid text.

Comment: Casual inspection of my download of `txt.tsv` indicates no 0xa0 character at the offset indicated in the question, but plenty of 0xa0 characters which are apparently representing hard spaces, and 0xac characters in a position which indicates a currency indicator as well as 0xae which apparently is the ®‎ symbol. This is *almost* consistent with CP1252 or ISO-8859-1 (which of course are very similar), but the 0xac doesn't fit with either. Maybe see also https://cdn.rawgit.com/tripleee/8bit/master/encodings.html#ac *(cough.)*

Comment: In my case, I had a text file with Windows CRLF instead of Unix LF.

Answer (score 4):

If someone works on Turkish data, then I suggest this line:

```
df = pd.read_csv("text.txt",encoding='windows-1254')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ds = pd.read_csv('/Dataset/test.csv', encoding='windows-1252')
```

Works fine for me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the input has a stray `'\xa0'`, then it's not in UTF-8, full stop.

Yes, you have to either recode it to UTF-8 (see: `iconv`, `recode` commands, or a lot of text editors and IDEs can do it), or read it using an 8-bit encoding (as all the other answers suggest).

What you should ask yourself is - what is this character after all (`0xa0` or 160)?
Well, in many 8-bit encodings it's a non-breaking space (like `&nbsp;` in HTML). For at least one DOS encoding it's an accented "a" character. That's why you need to look at the result of decoding it from the 8-bit encoding.

BTW, sometimes people say "UTF-8", and they mean "mostly ASCII, I guess". And if it was a non-breaking space, they weren't that far:

```
In [1]: '\xa0'.encode()
Out[1]: b'\xc2\xa0'
```

One exptra preceeding `'\xc2'` byte would do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered the same issue and worked while using latin1 encoding, refer to the sample code to apply in your codebase. Give a try if above resolution doesn't work.

```
df=pd.read_csv("../CSV_FILE.csv",na_values=missing, encoding='latin1')
```

Answer (score 1):

i have the same error message for .csv file, and This Worked for me :

```
     df = pd.read_csv('Text.csv',encoding='ANSI')
```