# Getting the below error while trying to read a CSV file in python

Tags: python, pandas

```
 File "<ipython-input-10-9cc4e896b568>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.read_csv('temp.csv')

  File "C:\Users\nivetha.n\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 646, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\Users\nivetha.n\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 401, in _read
    data = parser.read()

  File "C:\Users\nivetha.n\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 939, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)

  File "C:\Users\nivetha.n\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1508, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 848, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas\parser.c:10415)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 870, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\parser.c:10691)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 947, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\parser.c:11728)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 1049, in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_column_data (pandas\parser.c:13162)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 1108, in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_tokens (pandas\parser.c:14116)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 1206, in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_with_dtype (pandas\parser.c:16172)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 1222, in pandas.parser.TextReader._string_convert (pandas\parser.c:16400)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 1458, in pandas.parser._string_box_utf8 (pandas\parser.c:22072)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 0: invalid start byte


pd.read_csv('temp.csv')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-11-9cc4e896b568>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.read_csv('temp.csv')

  File "C:\Users\nivetha.n\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 646, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\Users\nivetha.n\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 401, in _read
    data = parser.read()

  File "C:\Users\nivetha.n\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 939, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)

  File "C:\Users\nivetha.n\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1508, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 848, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas\parser.c:10415)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 870, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\parser.c:10691)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 947, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\parser.c:11728)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 1049, in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_column_data (pandas\parser.c:13162)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 1108, in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_tokens (pandas\parser.c:14116)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 1206, in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_with_dtype (pandas\parser.c:16172)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 1222, in pandas.parser.TextReader._string_convert (pandas\parser.c:16400)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 1458, in pandas.parser._string_box_utf8 (pandas\parser.c:22072)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 0: invalid start byte


import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding("ISO-8859-1")
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-12-b416bfca896f>", line 2, in <module>
    sys.setdefaultencoding("ISO-8859-1")

AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'


pd.read_csv('temp.csv')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-13-9cc4e896b568>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.read_csv('temp.csv')

  File "C:\Users\nivetha.n\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 646, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\Users\nivetha.n\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 401, in _read
    data = parser.read()

  File "C:\Users\nivetha.n\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 939, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)

  File "C:\Users\nivetha.n\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1508, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 848, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas\parser.c:10415)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 870, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\parser.c:10691)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 947, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\parser.c:11728)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 1049, in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_column_data (pandas\parser.c:13162)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 1108, in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_tokens (pandas\parser.c:14116)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 1206, in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_with_dtype (pandas\parser.c:16172)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 1222, in pandas.parser.TextReader._string_convert (pandas\parser.c:16400)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 1458, in pandas.parser._string_box_utf8 (pandas\parser.c:22072)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: ['utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 4276: invalid start byte](//stackoverflow.com/a/48067785)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 4276: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48067514/utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa0-in-position-4276-invalid-start-byte)

Answer (score 0):

use `pd.read_csv('temp.csv', encoding='latin-1')`