# why does Unicode Decode Error message appear when I load a dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

I have converted an Excel file to csv, the goal is to analyse this dataset with python. So after importing my modules and the Dataset by using this code

```
Import pandas as pd
Import numpy as np
Import matplotlib as mlt

pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
```

I had the following message:

```
"'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 6: invalid start byte"
```

I searched on the web but none of those solutions applied to my issue and to be honest I don't know what to do.

Comment: You need to look into encoding. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48067514/utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa0-in-position-4276-invalid-start-byte

Comment: Can you share filename.csv? Probably your file has another encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need know what **character encoding** your file realy is. It's not UTF-8.

There are lots of different character encodings, sometimes the Excel change encoding to 'iso-8859-1' or 'cp1252', it's crazy.

Here is a important info that every IT person must know: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

To solve your problem, there at least three options:

1) Try some of possibilites (latin1, cp1252, etc):

```
df= pd.read_csv('file.csv',encoding ='latin1')
```

2) Save your files with UTF-8 encoding(or other original) before read. Probably Windows change the encoding after you open it (Excel) and update some row.

3) One way to figure it out is to try and test a bunch of different character encodings and see if any of them work. A better way, though, is to use the chardet module to try and automatically guess what the right encoding is. It's not 100% guaranteed to be right, but it's usually faster than just trying to guess:

```
import chardet

# look at the first ten thousand bytes to guess the character encoding
with open('file.csv', 'rb') as rawdata:
    result = chardet.detect(rawdata.read(10000))

# check what the character encoding might be
print(result)

{'encoding': 'Windows-1252', 'confidence': 0.99, 'language': ''}

# read in the file with the encoding detected by chardet
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', encoding='Windows-1252')
```