# Problems in loading a csv dataset in python

Tags: python

I have to load a dataset in Python 3.10.5 using the pandas `read_csv` line. The problem is that I get the following error:

```
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 169: invalid start byte`
```

What's the problem and what should I do?

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48067514/utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa0-in-position-4276-invalid-start-byte#48067785

Comment: Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python

Comment: Thank you all. I've just resolved my problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.